# Byte can't be cast to the desired output type Bool

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I tried to run the bert_capsnet model from this repo https://github.com/siat-nlp/MAMS-for-ABSA, but I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 8, in <module>
    train(config)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/MAMS-for-ABSA/train/train.py", line 66, in train
    logit = model(input0, input1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/MAMS-for-ABSA/src/aspect_term_model/bert_capsnet.py", line 66, in forward
    sentence_mask = segment_mask & ((1 - bert_segment).byte())
RuntimeError: result type Byte can't be cast to the desired output type Bool
```

Could someone help plz

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

you can try: `sentence_mask = segment_mask & (1 - bert_segment).byte() -> sentence_mask = segment_mask & (1 - bert_segment).bool()`.
or -> `((1 - bert_segment).byte()) & segment_mask`.

The former get bool type mask, the latter get int8 type mask like `[[[1,0,0...],[1,1,0,...]],...]`. In practice, I do not find different.